# How to scatter/arrange all the tables in database model (workbench)?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have around 71 tables and if i open them for creating a model in workbench all overlap as below
[image: All tables overlapping]

If i use the auto layout under arrange section then max i can get is as below
[image: partial arrangement]

How to auto arrange them without any overlapping ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no perfect layout tool. What you get is the best you can get automatically. After that fine tune your layout manually. Btw, make sure you have enough space for all objects by adding more pages if necessary (see `menu -> Model -> Diagram Properties and Size...`) before you run the auto layout.